# Neo4j slow loading

Tags: neo4j

I'm crawling(using sampling API) twitter and saving the 
crawled data into a Neo4j database.
When the total number of nodes exceed 20,000, my neo4j takes for ever to start.
It will just stoping at "...waiting for server to be ready ..." and nothing happens.
I normally wait for about 5~10 mins before I terminate the start, and so far I was unable to start process the server with that amount of node.

However, when I remove the "data" directory everything will start just fine.

I have inspected the neo4j.log file and found the following as well:

> May 26, 2013 9:21:53 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
>   INFO: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1

I was wondering does Neo4j loads everything into memory during the service startup ?
What should I do to speed up the startup time of the service ?

Comment: Not it doesn't. Can you share more details on how you load your data and how you cleanly shutdown the database?

Comment: How much RAM does your server have and how much is allocated to Neo4j? Are there other databases or ram intensive applications running on the same server?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to check with initial memory recommendation using: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin-memrec/

And then change heap (it uses heap to store state of the graph along with query etc).